# SQLAlchemy get SQL INSERT statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is any way to get INSERT/UPDATE statement before commiting?

I mean if I create object

```
order = Order(qty=1, comment='ccc')
session.add(order)
```

I'd like to get

```
INSERT INTO "Orders" ("qty", "comment") VALUES ("2", "ccc");
```

before I commit transaction.

Comment: When you say "get", do you mean to get the actual SQL text? If so, what do you plan on doing with the text? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you planning on logging? If so, you can change SQLAlchemy logging to log the resulting SQL statements.

Comment: No, I need to get SQL "text" and use it inside application. Not SQLAlchemy echo logging output

Comment: just curious: why? how do you use it inside application? on one particular object or the whole session?

Comment: I'd like to get SQL and execute it remotely